# How to hide "input" while using ButtonBar?

Tags: cells, interface, button

I used a ButtonBar. When I click a button (in Output) it unhide all my hidden code (Input). How to overcome this issue?

UPD: requested example

Input:

```
ButtonBar[{
  "Subsuperscript[E, concrete, creep]"   :> Print[Ebτ],
  "Subsuperscript[E, concrete, Bulichev]":> Print[EbBul],
  "Subsuperscript[γ, b1-3, γf]"          :> Print[γb3f /1.3],
  "Subsuperscript[γ, b1-4, γf]"          :> Print[γb1 γb2 γb3 γb4 /1.3],
  "Subscript[γ, b1-4]"                   :> Print[γb4f],
  "Subsuperscript[RR, b1, γ3]"           :> Print[Rb1 γb3f ],
  "Subsuperscript[R, b1, γ4]"            :> Print[Rb1 γb4f],
  "Subscript[σ, z]"                      :> Print[σz]
}]
```

After evaluation there eight buttons in Output. I double clicking the output cell and hide Input cell. 
But after clicking on any button the Input opens. I want to make it hidden until i want to open it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually select the input cell, you can uncheck the "Open" property in: the top-bar menu: `Cell` > `Cell Properties` .  It should stay closed until you open it again.

[image]

turns into:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can select the cell with the code, go to Menu/Cell/CellProperties and uncheck "Open". In this case, your code cell will always be closed.

In addition, do not write the string:`"Subsuperscript[E, concrete, creep]"`, as the button name, since it makes the button name the whole string as you write it, that is, with the word "Subsuperscript", the square brackets etc. In addition, the buttons are too small:

[image]

The better way please see below. Because of my laziness I only make a bar with two of your buttons:

```
ButtonBar[{"\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(concr\), \(creep\)]\)" :>
    Print[Eb\[Tau]], 
  "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(concr\), \(Bulichev\)]\)" :> 
   Print[EbBul]}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

looking as follows:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you! About button names: in Mathematica I use ctrl+6 -> ctr+5 and it got just the same names as yours. In my example the string transformed after "copy as -> plain text" . Anyway, thank you for info, it will come in handy.

Comment: Yes, I also type this using shortcuts, a bit different, since I have another keyboard. And this: `"\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(concr\), \(creep\)]\)"` it is simply how it is transformed when I copy-paste my expression into the StackExchange window. Though, you may, of course, use a box language.

Comment: oh... Now I see where was a problem... I just need to simple copy (not as a plain text) in future... Thank you!

Comment: @E.Delacroix and Alexei, something shorter: `MapAt[ToExpression[#, StandardForm, HoldForm] &, #, {1, All, 1}] &@
 ButtonBar[{ ...}, FrameMargins -> 5]`

Answer (score 2):

You can add following code to the cell whose code you want to hide:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellOpen -> Dynamic[Not@codehide]];
```

This will make it hidden according to the value of the `codehide`. Just evaluate it to True if you want hide the code or otherwise to show it. I usually put the checkbox onto the always visible part of the interface to have the real-time access to "codehiding"